# Jenkins Sonar Job aborted by anonymous. Weird job build behaviour

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I keep facing very weird issue integrating Jenkins and Sonar.
I have a maven project that I build and run SonarQube analysis via maven command line (with import of the Sonar server predefined variables).
When I run the Jenkins job first time, it *may be* green. The next job is "aborted by anonymous" without any logs provided. The third job is getting broken build with 401 error, saying I am not authorized to Sonar.

If I re-enter and re-save THE SAME PASSWORD to the Jenkins Sonar configuration, I *may get* the green build for one time again.

Has anyone faced such kind of Jenkins Poltergeist before and what could be the issue?

EDIT: after every "first green build", Jenkins auto-restarts and resets credentials in most of my plugins (i.e. SonarQube, Gerrit-Sonar). This influences only username\password pairs, not SSH credentials.

EDIT #2:
Maven version: 3.3.9

Jenkins version: 1.653

SonarQube Plugin Version: 2.4.4

Comment: are you using the latest Jenkins Sonar plugin? Do you find anything in Jenkins logs which could explain the auto restart?

Comment: Yep, the plugin is the latest. The only thing I see in logs before restart is that the job is aborted by an anonymous user. Nothing more.

Comment: Please update your question to provide version numbers for mvn, Jenkins, and the sonar plugins you are using (**latest** will change change over time).

Comment: And what about this information from their page? `I am ok with a <5% probability of having to restart my Jenkins in the next two weeks because of a bug in the credentials plugin 2.1.4 Released 23-Jun-2016` , maybe there is bug in credentials plugin in latest version

Comment: @Hrabosch - might have a look, thanks!

Comment: Did you try it with older version?