# Jenkins resets username and password in Gerrit\Sonar plugin after autorestart

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I use Jenkins with Gerrit-Sonar plugin and face a very weird issue:

1. I configure the plugin to handle Gerrit REST API with my username\password
2. When I run the job the first time, it passes, but after it Jenkins goes to auto-restart, saying "Please wait, Jenkins is getting ready to work."
3. After this my credentials in plugin are reset to default ("jenkins"\"gibberish").
4. Build fails due to 401 to Gerrit

When I re-save the credentials, they are stored only till the next weird auto-restart.

Has anyone seen this issue before or what could be the cause of it?

Thanks!

Comment: is this being reset in Gerrit configuration or SonarQube config?

Comment: This is being reset in Gerrit Trigger configuration

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, could you please also look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455626/jenkins-sonar-job-aborted-by-anonymous-weird-job-build-behaviour - this is regarding the Sonar plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer for your question, but it may be a workaround: in the 1.0.8 version of Sonar-Gerrit plugin it has become possible to override Gerrit credentials on the plugin level.

Comment: *It is not an answer for your question* Then you should add a comment instead of an answer!